# Can't remove Parallels.app on macOS Catalina

Tags: terminal, catalina, error, macos

So I am trying to completely remove Parallels without having to wipe my drive. I found every hidden file all deleted fine except this one that has become a nuisance.

The app is located in:

```
/Library/StagedExtensions/Applications/Parallels Desktop.app
```

I have tried the following:

1. Disabled SIP.
2. Attempted to Change Permission by Get Info. (**FAILED > ERROR**)
3. Attempted to Change Permission by Terminal. (**FAILED > NO CHANGE**)
4. Attempted to Change Permission by the BatChmod app. (**FAILED > NO CHANGE**)
5. Tried some other commands I found online that also didn't work.

If you think you can help get rid of this app, I'd appreciate the time saved in not having to wipe my drive.

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to delete it? What are the permissions on the .app directory and on the .../Application folder?

Comment: okay well I just checked now, and the applications folder in that directs now gone. weird that it did that all by itself at a later point in time. but hey I'm cool with it. Thanks for your attempt to help me. take care!

Answer (score 0):

The Issue resolved itself, as the folder and file removed itself.